# Generated glyphs from FreeType containing segments of memory

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype

Implementing text rendering into my game engine using FreeType (2.10.1), I am encountering odd looking glyphs, containing the letter repeated four times, mirrored on the x axis and turned upside down.

Up above the desired letter there seems to be neighboring memory interpreted as glyph, which changes every run and causes a segfault on some launches.

This is what I get when I try to render the word *"sphinx"*.

[image: The word 'sphinx']

Here is the full example sentence *"sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow"* flipped horizontally and rotated 180 degrees.

[image: Example sentence, flipped horizontally and rotated 180 degrees]

---

I have compiled [this code](https://gitlab.com/wikibooks-opengl/modern-tutorials/tree/master/text01_intro) to rule out [my MinGW environment being erroneous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451714/why-is-ft-load-char-giving-me-a-garbage-glyph-bitmap).

I'm very sure my usage of OpenGL is not the issue, since my texture uploading and rendering code works for other images.

Currently I'm wrapping the important bits of the `FT_Glyph_Slot` in a struct called `Letter` and caching that struct. Removing the wrapping and caching did not fix the error.

---

Here are the relevant code snippets:

FreeType initialization.

```cpp
// src/library/services/graphics/font/FreeType.cpp

void FreeType::initialize() {
    Logger::info("Initializing FreeType");

    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&m_library)) {
        Logger::error("Could not initialize FreeType");

        return;
    }
}

void FreeType::useFont(const std::string& fontName, const unsigned int fontSize = 42) {
    Logger::info("Loading font " + fontName);

    if (FT_New_Face(m_library, fontName.c_str(), 0, &m_currentFace)) {
        Logger::error("Could not open font " + fontName);

        return;
    }

    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(m_currentFace, 0, fontSize);
}
```

The code using FreeType to create a `Letter`.

```cpp
// src/library/services/graphics/font/FreeType.cpp

std::shared_ptr<Letter> FreeType::getLetter(unsigned long character) {
    // Try loading from cache
    if (std::shared_ptr<Letter> letter = m_letters.get(std::to_string(character))) {
        return letter;
    }

    return loadLetter(character);
}

std::shared_ptr<Letter> FreeType::loadLetter(unsigned long character) {
    if (FT_Load_Char(m_currentFace, character, FT_LOAD_RENDER)) {
        Logger::error("Could not load character " + std::string(1, character));

        return std::shared_ptr<Letter>();
    }

    FT_GlyphSlot& glyph = m_currentFace->glyph;

    Letter letter = {
            .id = character,
            .textureId = 0,
            .bitmap = {
                    .buffer = glyph->bitmap.buffer,
                    .width = glyph->bitmap.width,
                    .height = glyph->bitmap.rows
            },
            .offset = {
                    .x = glyph->bitmap_left,
                    .y = glyph->bitmap_top
            },
            .advance = {
                    .x = glyph->advance.x,
                    .y = glyph->advance.y
            }
    };

    std::shared_ptr<Letter> sharedLetter = std::make_shared<Letter>(letter);

    cache(sharedLetter);

    return sharedLetter;
}

void FreeType::cache(std::shared_ptr<Letter> letter) {
    m_letters.add(std::to_string(letter->id), letter);
}
```

The graphics system initializing FreeType

```cpp
// src/library/services/graphics/opengl/OpenGLGraphics.cpp

void OpenGLGraphics::initialize(int windowWidth, int windowHeight) {
    // ... OpenGL initialization

    m_freeType.initialize();
    m_freeType.useFont("../../../src/library/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
}
```

The code getting the `Letter` in the text renderer.

```cpp
// src/library/services/graphics/opengl/OpenGLGraphics.cpp

void OpenGLGraphics::drawText(const std::string &text, Vector2f location) {
    for (auto iterator = text.begin(); iterator < text.end(); ++iterator) {
        std::shared_ptr<Letter> letter = m_freeType.getLetter(*iterator);

        if (!letter->textureId) {
            std::shared_ptr<Texture> tex = 
                ImageLoader::loadFromCharArray(
                    letter->bitmap.buffer, 
                    letter->bitmap.width, 
                    letter->bitmap.height
                );

            letter->textureId = tex->id;
            m_freeType.cache(letter);
        }

    // ... OpenGL text rendering
    }
}
```

The code for generating a `Texture` from the `bitmap->buffer`.

```cpp
// src/library/services/graphics/opengl/util/ImageLoader.cpp

std::shared_ptr<Texture>
ImageLoader::loadFromCharArray(const unsigned char *image, const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height) {
    std::shared_ptr<Texture> texture = std::make_shared<Texture>();

    texture->width = width;
    texture->height = height;

    glGenTextures(1, &texture->id);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture->id);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (GLsizei) width, (GLsizei) height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    return texture;
}
```

---

If the supplied code snippets should not suffice, I will gladly add more.
This project is open source and available [here on GitHub](https://github.com/shvrd/engine-services).

Comment: You left out the most important part of the code: how do you put `letter->bitmap.buffer` into a texture?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the feedback, I have added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume that FreeType always generates 8-bits-per-channel RGBA images, but it does not.

You need to check `bitmap.pixel_mode` to see what image format you got.

Usually it will be either `FT_PIXEL_MODE_GRAY`, meaning 8-bits-per-pixel greyscale, or `FT_PIXEL_MODE_MONO`, meaning 1-bit-per-pixel monochrome.

See [the manual](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-basic_types.html#ft_pixel_mode) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much, changing the `GL_RGBA` to `GL_RED` to just use one grayscale 8-bit channel in the `glTexImage2D()` call resolved my problem. :)

Comment: @thekatze It might work in most cases, but for extra safery I suggest at least checking that `bitmap.pixel_mode == FT_PIXEL_MODE_GRAY`.